# Unable to use --exclude-perf option in perf command

Tags: performance-testing, perf

I'm trying to benchmark my application using perf. The application is c++ based and I want to evaluate

```
L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,cycles,instructions,cache-references,cache-misses,bus-cycles,branch-misses
```

I want to avoid seeing perf events in my output to make it more easily readable. Trying to run following command to capture the output:

```
perf record -g -e "L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,cycles,instructions,cache-references,cache-misses,bus-cycles,branch-misses" --exclude-perf Binary-name
```

but above mentioned command is failing with following error:

```
--exclude-perf option should follow a -e tracepoint option

 Usage: perf record [options] [command]

 or: perf record [options] -- command [options]

 --exclude-perf    don't record events from perf itself
```

If I don't use `--exclude-perf` option then my command runs just fine without any error.

Let me know what mistake I'm making while adding the option --exclude-perf

Comment: Why not just use interactive `perf report` and focus on your application PID? Also, there should be no perf-related samples as you does single-process profiling, not the whole system profiling when perf will profile itself.

Answer (score 2):

`--exclude-perf` is not for sampling/profiling events like you used (Hardware CPU counters). Is it only for tracepoint events:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-record.txt

```
151 --exclude-perf::
152         Don't record events issued by perf itself. This option should follow
153         a event selector (-e) which selects tracepoint event(s). It adds a
154         filter expression 'common_pid != $PERFPID' to filters. If other
155         '--filter' exists, the new filter expression will be combined with
156         them by '&&'.
```

It uses filters and filters are to be attached to tracepoint events.